# How to get values of all the checkboxes checked using android kotlin? I am getting null pointer Exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, checkboxlist, android-checkbox

for logic of the question you can refer to this question:-
[question Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72344861/how-to-select-multiple-checkboxes-using-one-checkbox-in-android-kotlin)

After lots of efforts I have came to this point. Please help me solving this problem.

Here is activity code:-

```
class CheckboxesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var adapter: CheckboxAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trail)
        recyclerView =findViewById(R.id.trail_rv)

        val list = listOf(
            RowModel(RowType.TopHeader, "", "", false),
            RowModel(RowType.Course, "", "Science", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Physics", "Science", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Math", "Science", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Chemistry", "Science", false),
            RowModel(RowType.Course, "", "Arts", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Economics", "Arts", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "History", "Arts", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Political Science", "Arts", false),
            RowModel(RowType.Course, "", "Commerce", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Accountancy", "Commerce", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Business Studies", "Commerce", false),
            RowModel(RowType.SubjectRow, "Physical Education", "Commerce", false)
        )

        adapter = CheckboxAdapter(this, list)
        adapter.setList(list)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.showTextBtn).setOnClickListener {
            selectedCheckboxes!!.clear()
            val checkboxesValue: String = selectedCheckboxes!!.joinToString(separator = ";")
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ShowTextView).text = checkboxesValue
        }

    }
}
```

here is my adapter code:-

```
class CheckboxAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    var productList: List<RowModel>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckboxAdapter.TableViewHolder>() {


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TableViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = productList[position]

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
        holder.checkBox.isChecked = item.isChecked

        val params: ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams =
            holder.checkBox.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

        when (item.rowType) {
            RowType.TopHeader -> {
                holder.checkBox.text = "All Courses"

                holder.checkBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                holder.checkBox.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD

                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                holder.checkBox.layoutParams = params

            }
            RowType.Course -> {

                holder.checkBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.checkBox.text = item.category


                holder.checkBox.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                holder.checkBox.layoutParams = params

            }
            RowType.SubjectRow -> {

                holder.checkBox.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.checkBox.text = item.subjectName
                holder.checkBox.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT
                params.setMargins(convertDpToPixel(20f, context).toInt(), 0, 0, 0)
                holder.checkBox.layoutParams = params
            }
        }


        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (item.isChecked != isChecked) {
                item.isChecked = isChecked

                when (item.rowType) {
                    RowType.TopHeader -> {
                        val indexList = mutableListOf<Int>()
                        productList.filter { it.rowType != RowType.TopHeader }.forEach {
                            it.isChecked = isChecked
                            indexList.add(productList.indexOf(it))
                        }
                        indexList.forEach {
                            notifyItemChanged(it)
                        }
                    }
                    RowType.Course -> {
                        val indexList = mutableListOf<Int>()
                        productList.filter { it.rowType == RowType.SubjectRow && it.category == item.category }
                            .forEach {
                                it.isChecked = isChecked
                                indexList.add(productList.indexOf(it))
                            }
                        indexList.forEach {
                            notifyItemChanged(it)
                        }
                        isAllItemsSameStatus() //for header

                    }
                    RowType.SubjectRow -> {
                        isAllItemsSameStatus(item.category) //set prep area accordingly
                        isAllItemsSameStatus() //set top header
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        when (item.rowType) {
            RowType.SubjectRow -> {
                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked)
                    selectedCheckboxes?.add(holder.checkBox.text.toString())
                if (!holder.checkBox.isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, holder.checkBox.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    selectedCheckboxes?.remove(holder.checkBox.text.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TableViewHolder {
        return TableViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.rv_trail,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    class TableViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val checkBox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trailCheckbox)

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = productList.size


    fun setList(profiles: List<RowModel>) {
        productList = profiles
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun isAllItemsSameStatus(cat: String? = null) {

        val row: RowModel
        var isChecked: Boolean = true
        var position: Int = 0

        if (cat != null) {
            val catRow = productList.find { it.rowType == RowType.Course && it.category == cat }
            catRow?.let {
                val subList =
                    productList.filter { it.category == it.category && it.rowType == RowType.SubjectRow }
                isChecked = subList.filter { it.isChecked }.size == subList.size
                position = productList.indexOf(catRow)
            }
            if (catRow == null)
                return
            else
                row = catRow
        } else {
            row = productList[0]
            isChecked =
                productList.filter { it.rowType != RowType.TopHeader && it.isChecked }.size == productList.size - 1
            position = 0
        }

        updateHeader(row, isChecked, position)
    }


    private fun updateHeader(item: RowModel, isChecked: Boolean, position: Int) {
        if (item.isChecked != isChecked) // no need to update if no change
        {
            item.isChecked = isChecked
            notifyItemChanged(position)

        }
    }

    private fun convertDpToPixel(dp: Float, context: Context): Float {
        return dp * (context.resources
            .displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
    }

    companion object {
        var selectedCheckboxes: MutableList<String>? = null
    }

}
```

here is my model code:-

```
data class RowModel (
    val rowType: RowType,
    val subjectName: String,
    val category: String,
    var isChecked: Boolean = true)

enum class RowType(val id : Int) {

    TopHeader(1),
    Course(2),
    SubjectRow(3);

}
```

here is activity_trail layout code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CheckboxesActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/trail_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showTextBtn"
        style="@style/ButtonTransparent"
        android:text="@string/save"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ShowTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

The logic of the question is :-

I am trying to make to activity that if:- 1)all courses checkbox is selected then all other checkboxes should be checked and vice versa.

2)all science button is checked then all other subjects buttons should be selected and vice versa. Same for all other subjects as well.

3)if any course button is not checked then all courses button should also not be checked. Same for all subjects as well.

After clicking showTextBtn (Button). The app is crashing. Here is the crash report:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.trail.CheckboxesActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(CheckboxesActivity.kt:45)
        at com.trail.CheckboxesActivity.$r8$lambda$Q7Wv2MEY_mNrpZmgjbfsuGABR0o(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.trail.CheckboxesActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Here I am trying to get the text of all the selected checkboxes.
Show that text in the textView.
Every other thing is working fine but the problem is only while getting the values of selected checkboxes text app is crashing.
If possible can you tell me if how can I use string-array instead of typing all these list?

Comment: a recyclerview will be creating (and recreating views), you need to know whether or not every individual item has been checked or not, so i would suggest adding in some boolean flag to each of the items being bound by your recycler (which you already have). then, when your checkbox is checked/unchecked you can use a callback to your fragment/activity to do whatever you want to see if everything that you want is checked or not

Comment: I have never tried callback. Can you please tell me the changes in the code required.?Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException. On which statement? And if that pointer is null then do not use that pointer, do not execute that statement then but display a toast to tell the user. Please solve first.

Comment: Can you post the `activity_trail` layout?

Comment: I have added activity_trail layout.

Comment: The NullPointerException is while getting the values of checked checkboxes text. I cannot just use toast to show checked checkboxes text values. I have to use those values in other functions as well.

Comment: The problem is in these lines in activity after clicking the button:- selectedCheckboxes!!.clear()
            val checkboxesValue: String = selectedCheckboxes!!.joinToString(separator = ";")

Comment: @blackapps First of all you should read the question properly. All the details were already mentioned in the question. Read the last few lines of the question. This is not the way to talk with anyone. We should respect each other. Lots of efforts have been taken on this question. There is no such question on stack overflow. Everything was clearly mentioned. This can be very useful to other programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using :-

```
var selectedCheckboxes: MutableList<String>? = null
```

use:-

```
var selectedCheckboxes: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
```